# How to add new unique element to List

Tags: java

I have a List of 100000 Objects. And its unique list. I want a add a new object to it. But the condition to add is it should be unique meaning, if the new element is already in the list, should not add to the list and should throw exception. Please let me know if there is idea.

Comment: You need to look at sets - preferably make the list a set

Comment: Use `Set` instead of `List`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good reason to use a `List`, e.g., because order matters to you, just use `contains` to check whether the element you want to add is already in the list:

```
public void addUnique(Object element) throws NotUniqueException {
    if (list.contains(element)) {
        throw new NotUniqueException(list, element);
    } else {
        list.add(element);
    }
}
```

However, for 100,000 objects, `contains` will be slow because it has to perform a linear search.

An alternative would be if your lists stores your objects in some natural order, e.g., an order that can be described with a `java.util.Comparator`. In that case, instead of using `contains`, you could use a binary search, to cut down the search from O(n) to O(log(n)):

```
public void addUnique(Object element) throws NotUniqueException {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, element, comparator);
    if (index >= 0) {
        throw new NotUniqueException(list, element);
    } else {
        list.add(index, element);
    }
}
```

However, the downside is that your `add` now becomes more expensive, because in order to keep the list sorted, some elements have to be moved to make space for the new element. That makes your `add` a linear operation.

A data structure that gives you both order and fast `contains` and fast `add` is a sorted tree, so you might want to evaluate whether that's an option for you.

Finally, you could combine a `Set` with a `List`, i.e., store every element in both: the set gives you fast `contains` while the list retains order of the elements. With this approach, you're not limited to a specific order defined by a `Comparator` but you can simply use the order of insertion:

```
public void addUnique(Object element) throws NotUniqueException {
    if (set.contains(element)) {
        throw new NotUniqueException(list, element);
    } else {
        list.add(element);
        set.add(element);
    }
}
```

This is basically what `LinkedHashSet` does for you - see also Peter Walser's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set, it contains only unique results http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use `Set` rather `List`.

But though you can get it -

```
List<Object> list =...;
public boolean add(Object obj){
    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>(list);
    return set.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: I am already having the list object with me, If I convert the list to Set, it will take lot of time.

Comment: @Umesh, any good IDE should be able to refactor this easily... `List` is really going to do more damage in the long run, so it's worth every minute of refactoring.

Comment: We cannot refactor it, its a big change for our app.

Comment: @Umesh, you can just use `contains()` then to check, but do be warned, this is going to be a huge performance issue, and it's going to get bigger and bigger as time moves on. I strongly advise you to spend the necessary time and do the refactoring, even if it takes a whole day (do check out your IDE's refactoring tools though, because this really should be easy to change). `List` and `Set` have very similar interfaces, so there shouldn't be much change involved anyway.

Comment: I am agree with rid it will be bottleneck situation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Set` data structure for your requirement. But it will not throw exception if you try to add new duplicate.

If you already have the list then you can create `Set` using

```
Set<YourType> foo = new HashSet<YourType>(yourList);
```

Comment: Converting list to Set is a big performance hit for 1 lack objects

Comment: @Umesh, could be true. I just showed a way :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` instead of `List`. If you really want to have a List, consider following example.

```
   List<String> myList=new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("asd");
    myList.add("asf");
    myList.add("asf");
    Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(myList);
    set.add("newString");
    myList.clear();
    myList.addAll(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the insertion order is important, use `LinkedHashSet` instead, which is basically a set but also tracks the element within a list to allow iterating over the elements in the same order as they were inserted (as with a list).

As for the exception when attempting to add a duplicate element, you can check if the element was added by verifying that the `add(..)` method returned `true` and throw an `Exception` otherwise, or by creating a specialized subclass which does this check:

```
public class UniqueItemList <E> extends LinkedHashSet<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add (E e) {
        checkContains(e);
        return super.add(e);
    };

    @Override
    public boolean addAll (Collection<? extends E> collection) {
        for (E e : collection) {
            add(e);
        }
        return !collection.isEmpty();
    }

    private void checkContains (E e) {
        if (contains(e)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element was already added");
        }
    }
}
```